# Nested ng-repeat with dynamic array giving $diget error

Tags: angularjs

I have a static array of object with multiple key:value  where few values are json strings. Now i have to ng-repeat my static array but in each object i have to call a **function  JSON.parse(json_string)** to get objects and again to use ng-repeat.  Now i tried this approach but i am getting error.

> My HTML

```
<div class="col-xs-12 margin-b5" ng-repeat="school in schools">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-6 text-left boards">
            <a href="#">
                <span ng-repeat="board in getParsed(school.school_boards)">@{{board.boardname}}</span>
            </a>
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-6 text-right format">
            <a href="#">
                <span>Day Boarding</span>
            </a>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

> I have a simple function getParse(string) which has JSON.parse function only

But in above approach i get this errror

Click [here](https://docs.angularjs.org/error/$rootScope/infdig).

Comment: buddy, add your controller's code :) and if you may, a JSFiddle would be nicer

Comment: my controller is very long. schools is coming from an ajax call. and rest of thing is above. if need more info please comment

Comment: why don't you parse your whole json data in ajax call's success callback itself? That would be much easier.

Comment: parse the data at once and then try

Comment: But for that i'll have to also use ng-repeat. isn't it ?

Answer (score 0):

You can parse your whole data at once when you recieve it from ajax call.
Try the following code. I can only give you this as you haven't shared your controller code.

```
$http.get("Url").
success(function(data) {
    alert(data);
    $scope.schools =  angular.fromJson(data);
    }).
error(function(data) {
    alert("API failed");
    });
```

Now you can use `$scope.schools` in your ng-repeat. You don't have to parse data on every ng-repeat. Just parse the data once and then use it in your ng-repeat loop.